# find_or_create by, if found, does it update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

After reading the docs, it does say: "find the first user named "PenÃ©lope" or create a new one." and "We already have one so the existing record will be returned."

But I do want to be 100% clear about this .

If I do:

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett') do |user|
  user.last_name = 'Johansson'
end
```

and User **does** exist with both `first_name: 'Scarlett'` and `last_name: 'Johansson'``, will it update it or completely ignore it?

In my case, I would like to completely ignore it if it exists at all and wondering if `find_or_create` is the way to go.  Because I don't want to bother updating records with the same information.  I am not trying to return anything either.

Should I be using `find_or_create`, or just use `exists?`

Also, if `find_or_create` does act as a way to check if it exists and would ignore if it does, would I be able to use it that way?

**For example:**

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett') do |user|
  user.last_name = 'Johansson'
  puts "Hello" #if it doesn't exist
end
```

Would "Hello" puts if it doesn't exist and not puts if it does?

Comment: Just a little warning - apidock.com is not the official documentation. Its just an annoying site with way to much google juice. The official docs are https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, if you have one or more `User` records with the first name 'Scarlett', then `find_or_create_by` will return one of those records (using a LIMIT 1 query). Your code, as provided, will set - but not save - the `last_name` of that record to 'Johansson'.

If you do not have one or more records with the first name 'Scarlett', then a record will be created and the field `first_name` will have the value 'Scarlett'. Again, the `last_name` field will be set to 'Johansson', but will not be saved (in the code you provide; you might save it elsewhere).

In this code:

```
User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett') do |user|
  user.last_name = 'Johansson'
  puts "Hello" #if it doesn't exist
end
```

...you will always see "Hello" because `find_or_create_by` will always return a record (either a found one or a created one).

Comment: The way I want to use it is with a unique attribute.  So if it IS found, it will set the attribute but not save it? Is basically what you're saying? But if it isn't found, it will save it?

Comment: Did you find this correct/useful? If so, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Comment: No problem! Is using something like `if Model.exists?(param: param)` `Model.create` faster than using `find_or_create_by` ? Both for if it's found and if not?